# Angular (6) Routing Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I've run into a few oddities with the Angular 6 router, but this one is really frustrating.

Here's are the routes I have build in `routing-app.module.ts`:

```
 export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: HomeScreenComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginComponent,
                canActivate: [LoginGuard],
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'password',
        component: HeaderComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: UpdatePasswordComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'companies/:company_id',
        loadChildren: './facility/facility.module#FacilityModule',
        canLoad: [FacilityGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'password-reset',
        loadChildren: './general/password/reset-password/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordModule'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'not-found'
    }
];
```

Then, inside the Facility Module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: HeaderComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'account-rep',
                component: AccountRepDashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: FacilityDashboardComponent,
                resolve: { company: FacilityDashboardResolve },
                canActivate: [FacilityGuard]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'manifests',
        component: HeaderComponent,
        canActivate: [FacilityGuard],
        canActivateChild: [FacilityGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'deleted',
                component: ListDeletedFacilityManifestComponent,
                resolve: { manifests: ListDeletedFacilityManifestResolve }
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: FacilityManifestComponent,
                resolve: { company: ListFacilityManifestResolve }
            },
            {
                path: ':manifest_id/reconcile',
                component: FacilityReconcileComponent,
                resolve: { manifest: FacilityReconcileResolve }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'customers',
        loadChildren: './customer/facility-customer.module#FacilityCustomerModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'sites',
        loadChildren: './site/facility-site.module#FacilitySiteModule'
    }
];
```

This is where my problem comes in. If you try to navigate to `/login`, you end up hitting route inside the `FacilityCustomerModule`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HeaderComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: RootFacilityCustomerComponent,
                resolve: { site: DetailFacilityCustomerResolve },
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'edit',
                        component: EditFacilityCustomerComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: DetailFacilityCustomerComponent,
                        children: [
                            {
                                path: 'details',
                                component: FacilityCustomerDetailsTabComponent
                            },
                            {
                                path: 'sites',
                                component: FacilityCustomerSitesTabComponent
                            },
                            {
                                path: 'users',
                                component: FacilityCustomerUsersTabComponent
                            },
                            {
                                path: '',
                                redirectTo: 'details',
                                pathMatch: 'full'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: ListFacilityCustomerComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I can't make heads or tails of why the Router is matching this. I know it's hitting the redirect, because you end up at `/login/details`.

Maybe I just don't have enough knowledge about how the Angular Router works, but I would think that it hits the very first route `/login` and matches it, unless it builds the routes recursively, from the inside out?

Can anyone shed some light on this? I didn't have as much trouble with Angular 4 or 5, so it seems like things changed, and I'm just not sure how.

**EDIT:**

As requested, here are the decorators.

`RoutingAppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

`RoutingFacilityModule` & `RoutingFacilityCustomerModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

`AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        DataEntryModule,
        FacilityModule,
        UpdateModule,
        SupportModule,

        CtaModule,
        HeaderModule,
        HomeScreenModule,

        RoutingAppModule,
        ResetPasswordModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,

        LoginComponent,
        NotFoundComponent,
        NotPermittedComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AppErrorHandlerService,
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: AppErrorHandler
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please share your root module decorator configuratio. `ngModule({...`

Comment: @ibenjelloun Sure. I added them above. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have login-Component module?

Comment: @alokstar No. The `LoginComponent` is declared in the `AppModule`.

Comment: @EricR I actually mean the root module not the routing module.

Comment: @ibenjelloun Oh... my bad. Added that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using lazy loading you should not import the module in the root module.

You used lazy loading for the module `FacilityModule` which is imported in the root module.

There are also other lazy loaded modules imported in the root module, you should remove all the lazy loaded modules from the imports :

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DataEntryModule,
    UpdateModule,
    SupportModule,

    CtaModule,
    HeaderModule,
    HomeScreenModule,

    RoutingAppModule
],
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a go!